# Why is my data not rendering on initial page load using NextJS13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, zustand

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import Headertest from "@/components/Headertest";
import { useStore } from "@/store/index";

async function Page() {

  const { getEvents, events } = useStore.getState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, [events]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Headertest />
      {events.map((event) => (
        <div key={event.id}>{event.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Page;
```

This is a sample page in NextJS 13. I use Zustand for state management, but when the load the page initially it shows no data (only header). When it renders, it shows all data. How can I render my data on the initial page load?

Here is my action code for Zustand:

```js
getEvents: async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  // console.log(data)
  set({events: data});
  return data;
},
```

Comment: why it should be rendered on load? you are using useEffect - so the function getEvents will be triggered after component is loaded on client. By the way the code you provided is triggering infinite loop - useEffect should have [] as deps